# how to get ip address in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-address

How to get ip address from your country location in rails?

I try typing `request.remote_ip` in console but I get ip address `127.0.0.1`, this is localhost?... I won't to get ip address from country user derived.

I'm using gem named [`geokit-rails`](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) for getting country based ip address.

To get ip address from your location if i try this code :

```
Model.geocode(ip-addess)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a development host's external IP address rather than the "localhost" address or loopback address of 127.0.0.1, explicitly bind to the host's external IP address. By default servers may listen on 0.0.0.0 (any address) and the localhost address ends up being used when testing on the same host as the development host.

To bind explicitly using web brick for example:

```
rails server -b my.real.ip.address
```

To bind explicitly using apache/passenger or similar, in the apache config use:

```
Listen my.real.ip.address:port
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
  class ActionDispatch::Request
    def remote_ip
      "38.89.128.21"
    end
  end
```

in *config/environments/development* to spoof your IP to NYC (or anywhere you set the IP to be) when it's just going to be your local machine accessing it. You're overwriting that function. This is useful if you're doing geolocation stuff with the IP addresses.

Edit: I accidentally wrote */production* instead of */development*. Don't do that. Bad idea, all of your users would be from NY.

Answer (score 0):

It is [`request.remote_ip`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/remote_ip) that gives you the "Originating IP address".  Because in your development machine your server and client are the same you are getting `127.0.0.1`.

To confirm this visit your rails application from a different machine.

Comment: so its work if i already my app to server like heroku for example?

ok, thanks vee

Comment: @tardjo, yes that should work, but keep in mind that the IPs won't be real if the originating client is behind a proxy.  Please read the documentation on the `remote_ip` method from the link in my answer.